# Form won't submit info to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I've been building a site recently for a friend and I've gotten stuck on this one form. A button links to url in which this form is on and then once you fill out all the information and click submit, instead of returning you back to home.php it just removes the form from view and all you see is a blank new.php and it doesn't submit the information.

```
   <?php
 function renderForm($user, $rank, $position, $error)
 {
?>
 <?php 
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 
 <center>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username*</label>
    <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="rank">Rank</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="rank">
 <option value="1">Pending Rank</option>
 <option value="2">PVT</option>
</select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="position">Position</label>
    <input id="position" class="form-control" type="text" name="position" placeholder="MOG/GG" value="<?php echo $position; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Date">Date*</label>
    <input id="Date" class="form-control" type="text" name="date" placeholder="<?php echo date('d M y'); ?>" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Tag">Tag*</label>
    <input id="Tag" class="form-control" type="text" name="tag" placeholder="[]" value="<?php echo $tag; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="adt">ADT</label>
    <input id="adt" class="form-control" type="text" name="adt" placeholder="{TEST}" value="<?php echo $adt; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exp">EXP</label>
    <input id="exp" class="form-control" type="text" name="exp" placeholder="420" value="<?php echo $exp; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="reg">Regiment</label>
    <input id="reg" class="form-control" type="text" name="reg" placeholder="[P]" value="<?php echo $reg; ?>" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Notes">Notes</label>
    <input id="Notes" class="form-control" type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Notes" value="<?php echo $notes; ?>" />
  </div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</form>
<script>
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
});
</script>
<?php 
}

 include('config/db.php');

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 

 $user = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']));
 $rank = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['rank']));
 $position = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['position']));
 $date = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']));
 $tag = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['tag']));
 $adt = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['adt']));
 $exp = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['exp']));
 $reg = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['reg'])); 
 $notes = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['notes']));
 $datej = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']));

 if ($user == '' || $rank == '' || $date == '' || $tag == '')
 {
 $error = '<center>ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!</center>';

 @renderForm($user, $rank, $position, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 mysql_query("INSERT per SET user='$user', rank='$rank', position='$position', date='$date', tag='$tag', adt='$adt', exp='$exp', reg='$reg', notes='$notes', datej='$datej'", $db1)
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 include('logsadd.php');
 write_mysql_log('has added member <font color="black"><b>'. $user .'</b></font>.', $db);

 header("Location: home.php");
 }
 }
 else
  header("home.php");
 {
 @renderForm('','','');
 }?>
```

Comment: The way you are tackling this is a bit out dated,  You should check out the MySQLi extension or PDO in the future. Since I can't see what your database actually looks like it's hard to pin point the problem from the script alone.

Comment: Are these two separate parts, the form and all the stuff after the form? Like two different pages?

Comment: @Rasclatt No this is all on the same page.

Comment: Check for error logs. It seems php script had some fatal error. Also remove @ from @renderForm. It won't allow to report errors

Answer (score 0):

Your else looks like this

```
else
  header("home.php");
 {
 @renderForm('','','');
```

it should be

```
else
{
 // header should be inside the else part 
  header("Location:home.php"); 
 @renderForm('','','');
```